# XSD.exe not creating main class from xsd file, just classes for imported types

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd

I have an xsd for a communication service that describes response messages.  I'd like to create assosciated C# classes so I can serialize/deserialize and utilize strong typing, but XSD.exe is giving me a major headache.

The XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="co:core:restapi"
elementFormDefault="qualified"
xmlns="co:core:restapi"
xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:lpr="co:core">
<xs:import namespace="co:core" schemaLocation="Location.xsd"/>
<xs:import namespace="co:core" schemaLocation="List.xsd"/>
<xs:import namespace="co:core" schemaLocation="ListEntry.xsd"/>
<xs:import namespace="co:core" schemaLocation="Alert.xsd"/>

 <xs:complexType name="superType">

    <xs:choice>
        <xs:sequence>

            <xs:choice>

                <xs:element name="location">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>
                        </xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>

                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="site" type="lpr:location" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>

                <xs:element name="list">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>
                        </xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>

                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="list" type="lpr:list" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>

                <xs:element name="listentry">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>
                        </xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>

                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <xs:element name="delete" type="lpr:delete" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element name="entry" type="lpr:listentry" minOccurs="0"/>
                        </xs:choice>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>

      <xs:element name="alert">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:documentation>
          </xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>

        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="alert" type="lpr:alert" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>

    </xs:choice>

            <xs:element name="page">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>
                    </xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>

                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="next" type="xs:anyURI">
                            <xs:annotation>
                                <xs:documentation>
                                </xs:documentation>
                            </xs:annotation>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>

        </xs:sequence>

        <xs:element name="error" type="xs:string">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>
                </xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Essentially, the types will be filled in for the import namespaces, but there will be nothing created for the complex superType.

Comment: You have a bunch of warnings in the schema.  From VS menu : Project : Add New Item : Xml Schema.  Then select option to view and edit schema.  Paste your schema into view.  Errors and warnings will been seen in Error List like any compiler errors.

Comment: Ah, some of those were just my clumsy pasting of stuff here, some based on my changing of names just for posting it here.  I've edited to fix those issues, I think...The missing types are due to the missing import files (didn't want to rename and post everything here).  Issue is, I believe, the use of choice switch and how xsd treats it.

Comment: What are your headaches?  If you do not want to serialize everything than make the properties private.